# Spark Sql - mongoDb memory exceed limit. How to use 'allowDiskUse' in Spark

Tags: mongodb, scala, apache-spark

I have been struggling with one issue related to Spark mongo query execution limits.Below is the query that I’m passing to mongoDB from Spark and result gets stored in dataframe. But application throws error with sort exceeded memory limit (sample code and complete error is below). I can use ‘allowDiskUse:true’ option when I execute query in mongo shell but don’t find a way to pass that option from Spark.

I thought of increasing memory limit on mongoDB but Aggregation pipeline stages are limited to 100 MB and this is not configurable (response from mongoDB support team), so there is nothing I can do on mongoDB side.

Each document in the collection is big nested json document (each document is of <=2MB). I flatten document once I get result back from mongo. Also I’m not sending any sort command in query, but mongo engine seems to be  performing sort during query execution.

```
val ruleAssgnMatchQuery = """[{ $match: {"category":"abc","archive_flag": 
                              false, "general.active_flag":true} } ] """
  val ruleAssgnDf = spark.read.format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource")
          .option("spark.mongodb.input.uri", DSSConnectionURI)
          .option("spark.mongodb.input.collection", ruleAssgnCollName)
          .option("pipeline",ruleAssgnMatchQuery)
          .load()
```

Here is the error. I'm using Spark - 2.3.1, mongo-spark-connector - 2.4.0
com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 16820 (Location16820): 'Sort exceeded memory limit of 104857600 bytes, but did not opt in to external sorting. Aborting operation. Pass allowDiskUse:true to opt in.' on server 172.16.1.26:27017. The full response is { "ok" : 0.0, "errmsg" : "Sort exceeded memory limit of 104857600 bytes, but did not opt in to external sorting. Aborting operation. Pass allowDiskUse:true to opt in.", "code" : 16820, "codeName" : "Location16820" }

Comment: First thing, the connector version you are using isn't compatible with the spark version (ref. https://docs.mongodb.com/spark-connector/master/)

Comment: Secondly, you ought reading this https://docs.mongodb.com/spark-connector/master/scala/read-from-mongodb/ It might help you figure out how to pass options to your cluster. According to this doc [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/spark-connector/master/configuration/#spark-output-conf), that option isn't listed...

Comment: One more thing, that "query" you are executing is executed on MongoDB side. MongoDB connector doesn't support pushdown predicate (The mongo-connector team doesn't even know what that is...)